# Using AND command in SQL Server not giving expected result

Tags: sql

I am trying to write some code to identify whether 2 values in 1 table exist in another table before executing some other code. I find these:

```
select count(1)
from Team
where TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header = 'Home Team');

select count(1)
from Team
where TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header = 'Away Team');
```

both return the value 1 as expected, when the values are present in table Team column TeamName. However, this:

```
select count(1)
from Team
where TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header = 'Home Team')
AND TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header = 'Away Team');
```

returns 0 when (as far as I can see) it should combine the 1st two queries and return 1.
Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's more readable this way:

```
select count(1)
from Team
where TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header in ('Home Team', 'Away Team'))
```

To return 1 one way would be to decode the result:

```
select case when count(1) = 0 then 0 else 1 end
from Team
where TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header in ('Home Team', 'Away Team'))
```

Comment: changed to when count(1) = 2 then 1 else 0 but that showed me how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What your current query says is: Count all rows where TeamName is Home AND Away team.
Replace `AND`with `OR`: One team can either be home or away team:

```
select count(1)
from Team
where TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header = 'Home Team')
OR TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header = 'Away Team');
```

EDIT: And a quick and dirty way to just return 1:

```
select CASE WHEN count(1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
from Team
where TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header = 'Home Team')
OR TeamName IN (select Data FROM CSVTest_Match WHERE Header = 'Away Team');
```

Comment: Thanks. I see where I had gone wrong now. However, your solution returns 2 when both values are present. I would like to return 1 to state that the condition is true. This is why I was trying to use the AND operator so that both values had to exist.

Comment: Ahh, OK, then you have to use @tibtof 's answer. I just wanted to show you why you got the wrong result.

Comment: tibtof's answer is very neat indeed but also returns 2. I can use this method but if anybody can tell me how to return 1 it would be a bonus. Thanks

Comment: instead put count(1) try to put just the value 1